# Compare UIVIewController with Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use below code for get active viewController

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *controller = appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
```

I want to find that this viewController (controller) is which of my class,for this use below code but doesn't work

```
My classes:
First.m , First.h , First.xib
Second.m , Second.h , Second.xib
Third.m , Third.h , Third.xib

if([controller isKindOfClass:[First class]])
....
```

Comment: My guess: Your rootview controller may be bind in UInavigationcontroller or anyother... If yes, above code won't work..

Comment: Yes , i use tabbar and uinavigation

Comment: So You've to get correct instance, then check `isKindOfClass:`. it will work

Comment: how? please explain more

Comment: if you are using tabbar then check with if ([controller class] == [TabBarController class]) { }

Comment: ie appDelegate.window.rootViewController -> .viewControllers[0] (assuming it is tabbar controller) -> .viewControllers[0] (assuming it is navigation controller and view controller stack having first object as First

Comment: @SajjadZare Did you get my comment or do you want an answer in more detail?

Comment: @mani  Yes i got your comment,but i need more help !

Answer (score 0):

If your app's root view controller is a UINavigationController you can do this:

```
UIViewController *controller = ((UINavigationController*)appDelegate.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController;
```

Similarly, if it's a UITabBarController you can do this:

```
UIViewController *controller = ((UITabBarController*)appDelegate.window.rootViewController).selectedViewController;
```

Finally,

```
if ([controller isKindOfClass:[First class]]) {

}
```